# How to increse width of a column of Gantt Chart in Syncfusion ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, gantt-chart, syncfusion

How can I customize the width of a Gantt chart in Syncfusion ASP.NET MVC.

I am sharing a screen shot where i want to increase the width of "Task Name"

[image: Gantt Chart Screen Shot]

Comment: @TonyHinkle: Brother I don't understand what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem finally for Gantt Chart of SYNCFUSION "how to increase the width of a column and hide a column?"

Solution: Basically to work with Syncfusion gantt Column Width issue we need to write a js function named as "load"(or according to your demand) that finally called in Gantt Properties named Load: "load"

Here I shared my code snippet

```
    function load(args) {
        var col = this.getColumns();
        col[0].visible = false; // that hide first ID column
        col[1].width = "435px";
        col[2].width = "120px";
        col[3].width = "120px";
        col[4].width = "80px";
    }
```